# Verify organizational email by OAuth2 to give discord users a roles

Tags: discord, discord.js

we need an ideas about this.
Can we make a discord bot that will require user to login with our OAuth2 and then the bot will validate the email. if there's email inside our DB then the bot will grant a roles for this user. This is the scheme that inside our head, maybe we can have any advices and also the tech that can be used.
[image]

Thanks.

We already do some research about this DiscordJS Bot (https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/#a-quick-example) maybe can we use that tech? or is there any tech that already made that?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you've already covered the basics, such as creating a Discord app in the developer portal and adding the app to your Discord server to enable role addition (ensure it's added with the bot scope and has the required permissions, i.e., `MANAGE_ROLES`).

The guide [you linked](https://discordjs.guide/oauth2/#getting-an-oauth2-url) should be enough for your needs (*however it seems to be bit overkill depending on your needs, a simple web-server without any pages and only an api would also work*). However there are some additions you will have to do in order to get it to work.

1. You will have to use the `email` auth scope **as well** as `identify` (the guide only uses identify) - This will allow you to get the email linked with the discord account

> [List of auth scopes supported by discord](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources-oauth2-scopes)

> You can visit the Your app > OAuth > URL Generator page on the Discord developer portal if you need help generating a link with the mentioned scopes.

2. Get the user's email by making a request to [users/@me](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/user#get-current-user) with the authentication token you get from doing the oauth from step 1 (if you correctly did the step 1, then the returned json object should have `email` property)
3. Do the validation stuff you talked about in your question here. (check if the email is there), If it fails the validation you can do whatever you want
4. if the validation was successful you can use the Discord api to add the role to the user

NOTE: **You should use authentication token for a bot app in the api requests after this (NOT the users oauth token)**

> [API docs for adding a role](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member-role)

If you want you can even use [@discordjs/rest](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/rest/main) which was created by the same people who built the guide you linked. It will handle rate-limits and have proper validation for you inputs.

if i missed anything just comment and i will edit the answer with relevant information.